# Do every private framework we use need to be signed?

Tags: cocoa, code-signing, osx-mountain-lion

As stated in the question, if I have a private framework that's not signed (Do frameworks need to be signed?), is it required to have the framework signed in order to use the application without gatekeeper (assuming I did sign the application)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW5), this is not currently required, but it will be required in the future, so it's better to code signed it.